# Troubleshooting Fl_chart Package: Incorrect Line Chart Data with YYYYMM Format

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I am attempting to create a line chart representing the monthly sales data for a given year using the Fl_chart package.

One issue I'm encountering is that when I provide the x-axis data in the format [202209, 202210, 202301] (in yyyymm format), the chart displays data points like [202209, 202210, 202220, 202230, 202240, 202250, 202260, 202270, 202280, 202290, 202301]. This is causing the line chart to be drawn incorrectly.

```
LineChart(LineChartData(
                                gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
                                titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                    topTitles: AxisTitles(
                                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                            showTitles: isBlank)),
                                    rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                            showTitles: isBlank)),
                                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                            getTitlesWidget:
                                                getBottomTitles,
                                            showTitles: true),
                                        axisNameWidget: Text("Month"),
                                        axisNameSize: 30)),
                                lineBarsData: [
                                  LineChartBarData(
                                      isStrokeCapRound: true,
                                      dotData: FlDotData(show: false),
                                      belowBarData:
                                          BarAreaData(show: false),
                                      spots: [
                                        FlSpot(202209, 2500),
                                        FlSpot(202210, 2800),
                                        FlSpot(202301, 1800)
                                      ].toList())
                                ]))))))));
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please give code for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe some images of relevant graphs to help us best understand the problem, and take a read of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a more complete idea of what a well-asked question looks like :) People are unlikely to answer your question if it takes them more effort to understand what your problem is than it does to solve it!! ;)

Comment: @dwb question updated with code and resulting graph image